# Reader mysql keeps returning null

Tags: mysql, database, reader

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectCmd, myConnection);
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT idtolistsubsoorten FROM `vogelsoort` WHERE id= MAX (id)and vogelsoort.naam =@vogelsoortnam";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@vogelsoortnaam", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = vogel.Soortnaam;
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string idpape = reader.;
                        subid = Convert.ToInt64(idpape);
                    }
```

the reader keeps returning an null value

Comment: did you investigate the possibility that idtolistsubsoorten may really be null?

Answer (score 0):

are you mistaking in query you should write single or double quotas when you use string

```
 command.CommandText = "SELECT idtolistsubsoorten FROM `vogelsoort` WHERE id= MAX (id) and vogelsoort.naam =@vogelsoortnam";
```

Comment: just run this query in MySQL and tell me what is result

Comment: prepared statements should not be quoted

Comment: removed quoted now

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query has a mistake: There are two `FROM` commands:

```
SELECT idtolistsubsoorten 
FROM `vogelsoort` 
WHERE id= MAX (id)
FROM `vogelsoort`
and vogelsoort.naam = @vogelsoortnam
```

Try using this one instead:

```
SELECT idtolistsubsoorten 
FROM `vogelsoort` 
WHERE id= MAX (id)
and vogelsoort.naam = @vogelsoortnam
```

Also, you can try executing the query in your dbms before running it in PHP, this way you will have an error message with more verbose.